# Variation of the Spin Connection

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-spin, spinors, variational-calculus, supergravity

I am trying to get an explicit expression for the variation $\delta \omega_{\mu}^{\ ab} / \delta e_\mu^a$, but when doing the actual variation I end up with a series of 16 terms that I cannot simplify any further, though it should be possible to rewrite the resulting expression as a sum of covariant derivatives of the vielbein. The resulting identity is relevant for several calculations that involve spinors on curved spacetimes and Supergravity, but I cannot find a similar calculation or result anywhere for reference.

**Edit:** If someone knows a good Mathematica package to take variational derivatives of the vielbein and spin connection, that would also be very helpful.

---

Requiring the spin connection to be torsion free and compatible with the metric gives us the following constraint
$$
\nabla_\mu e_\nu^a = \partial_\mu e_\nu^a + \omega_{\mu\ b}^{\ a} e^b_\nu - \Gamma^{\ \lambda}_{\mu\ \nu} e^a_\lambda = 0
$$
This allows us to write the following expression for the spin connection in terms of the vielbein
$$
\begin{align}
\omega_{\mu}^{\ ab} =& e^{\nu a} \Gamma^\lambda_{\ \mu\nu} e^b_\lambda - e^{\nu a} \partial_\mu e_\nu ^{\ b} \\
    =& \frac{1}{2} e^{\nu a} g^{\lambda\sigma} \left( \partial_\mu g_{\sigma\nu} + \partial_\sigma g_{\nu\mu} - \partial_\nu g_{\mu\sigma} \right) - e^{\nu a} \partial_\mu e_\nu ^{\ b} \\
    =& \frac{1}{2}e^{\nu a}(\partial_\mu e_\nu^{\ b}-\partial_\nu e_\mu^{\ b})-\frac{1}{2}e^{\nu b}(\partial_\mu e_\nu^{\ a}-\partial_\nu e_\mu^{\ a})-\frac{1}{2}e^{\rho a}e^{\sigma b}(\partial_\rho e_{\sigma d}-\partial_\sigma e_{\rho d})e_\mu^{\ d} \\
    =& \frac{1}{2} e^{\nu [a} \left( \partial_{\mu} e_{\nu}^{b]} - \partial_{\nu} e_{\mu}^{b]} + e^{b]\sigma}e_\mu^d\partial_\sigma e_ {\nu d} \right)
\end{align}
$$
where I first wrote the Christoffel connection in terms of the metric and then used that $g_{\mu\nu} = e^a_\mu e^b_\nu \eta_{ab}$.

Does someone know a source where there is an expression for the following variational derivative?
$$
 \frac{\delta \omega_{\mu}^{\ ab}}{\delta e_\mu^a}
$$
I tried calculating it myself, but since the above expression has four bilinear terms in $e$ and two quartic terms in $e$, you will end up with $2 \times 4 + 4 \times 2 = 16$ terms after doing the actual variation. I have a lot of trouble rewriting this variation as a neat expression (and cannot find any references that mention it)

---

As a comparison, consider the variation of the Christoffel connection with respect to the metric.
$$
\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho} = g^{\mu\lambda} \Gamma_{\lambda\nu\rho} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\lambda} \left( \partial_\lambda g_{\nu\rho} + \partial_\nu g_{\rho\lambda} - \partial_\rho g_{\lambda\nu} \right) 
$$
When varying this expression you will also get a lengthy series of terms, but the trick is to see they can be rearanged as covariant derivatives of the Christoffel connection. I assume there must be a similar trick and expression to rewrite the variation of the spin connection in terms of covariant derivatives of the vielbein?
$$
\begin{align}
\delta \Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho} =& \Gamma_{\lambda\nu\rho} \delta g^{\mu\lambda} + g^{\mu\lambda} \delta \Gamma_{\lambda\nu\rho} \\
    =& \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\lambda} \left( \nabla_\lambda \delta g_{\nu\rho} + \nabla_\nu \delta g_{\rho\lambda} - \nabla_\rho \delta g_{\lambda\nu} \right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Are you comfortable with the mathematicians' coordinate-independent formalism? I suspect Lawson & Michelsohn's book on Spin geometry has some relevant results, but they will not be written in physicists' notation.

Comment: Could you maybe refer to a specific chapter or page you were thinking of? I have been looking through the book today, but besides a pile of awe-inspiring sections on Index Theorems and K-Theory I cannot seem to find what I am looking for. I would like to point out my question is not so much a conceptual one, it is a rather simple identity that I am looking for, the kind of which I would expect to be on the back page of most books on Supergravity (like the one by Freedman and Van Proeyen), however I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: It was just a shot in the dark---I'm sorry to have wasted your time. Indeed, you are probably better off looking through the SUGRA literature, but I wouldn't know anything about that either...

Comment: It's also a shot in the dark, but I don't think your premise is correct, the equation you start with is an almost triviality (it says the covariant derivative of the identity tensor is zero).

Instead maybe try starting with $\omega_{\mu\ \ \ b}^{\ a}=\frac{1}{2}(c_{bdc}+c_{cdb}-c_{dcb})e^c_\mu$, where $c^a_{\ bc}e_a=[e_b,e_c]$.

Comment: The equation I start with follows from the requirement that the spin connection should be torsion free and compatible with the metric. You can derive the same relation from the requirement that that $\nabla_\kappa g_{\mu\nu} =0$. I believe the relation you wrote down for $\omega_{\mu\ b}^{\ a}$ is essentially the same as the relation I eventually obtained this way for $\omega_{\mu}^{\ ab}$ (though I agree, written your way the expression for the spin connection does look somewhat more manageable). I tried calculating the variation in both cases, but without success.

Comment: You can get the variation of torsion free spin-connection from eq. (7.96) of the book 'Supergravity' by Freedman and Proeyen.

Also look at the equation right before sec. 3.1.2 and eq. (49) in https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.10044.

A Mathematica package to derive this result yourself can be 'Spinors' https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2662.

Answer (score 2):

Long time no answer! I only just saw the question and maybe someone will find this useful. We want the change in the spin connection as a result of varying the tetrad ${\bf e}_a$ while preserving the torsion-free condition.

The calculation is indeed a bit tedious, and when I needed it it took me several days. Here is what I get:

Define
$$
\delta e_{ij} =  {\bf e}_i\cdot \delta {\bf e}_j= \eta_{ib}[e^{*b}_\alpha \delta e_j^\alpha],
$$
then
$$
(\delta \omega_{ij\mu}) e^\mu_k 
 =-\frac 12\left\{(\nabla_j \delta e_{ik} -   \nabla_k  \delta e_{ij})
+( \nabla_k \delta e_{ji}-   \nabla_i  \delta e_{jk})
-( \nabla_i \delta e_{kj}-   \nabla_j \delta e_{ki})\right\}.\nonumber
$$